implementation passthrough from library in kotlin dsl
I can't figure out how to let my library pass another library to a main app. I know that sounds a little weird, so I'll try to explain the best I can. For a simple example, I have an annotation processor that I built that makes code generation much easier. I also have a library to hold UI elements and common functionality. In order to kind of package them together I went into my library gradle dsl file and added an implementation on the annotation processor...
library gradle file...
//... gradle file
dependencies {
  //... dependencies
  implementation(libs.annotations)
  kapt(libs.annotations)
  //... dependencies
}
//.. rest of gradle file

Then in my sample app that I am using to test all of this I am adding a dependency on the library
dependencies {
  implementation(libs.library)
}

However in my code when I try to annotate a class with my annotation I am getting an error
unresolved reference 'annotations'
Is there a way to allow my library to also provide my annotations?
If it matters I compile the library to an aar and then upload it to a private artifactory repo, which is then added to my sample app.

Replace:
implementation(libs.annotations)

with:
api(libs.annotations)

api() says "expose this library's public API as part of my library's public API". implementation() says "use this library, but do not make it available my library's consumers".

Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I knew there had to be a way and that I was missing something, glad it was something simple.

One more question if you don't mind. Would I put the kapt for the annotation processor in the library, or in the project that I am building and set the kapt to the library?

@NeglectedSanity: You need it wherever the annotations are. That could be both libraries, if both use the annotations. AFAIK, there is no api() equivalent for kapt(), and the consuming library will need its own kapt() line.
